# How can I call a function inside this function with parameters, if I don't have both name and args/kwargs?

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to run a celery task retry inside the current task, and want to simplify this call (I have about 15 tasks like this).

How can I call the function inside itself, if I don't have the name and the kwargs?

```
def f(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    __this_function__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, unless the answer you're looking for is  "You can do `f(a, b, c)`".

Comment: I need something like "self" for a function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname. 
And you may store your function names in a array.

Comment: If you have to put the code inside the function, there's no point in avoiding the function name or arguments. Why not put the retry code as a loop outside the function, or in a retry decorator?

Comment: @kwild: If that is so, I think you should edit your question to clarify.  I'm not sure why you're even mentioning kwargs if all you want is a way for a function to refer to itself (which, incidentally, isn't possible in a simple way, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063607/is-there-a-self-flag-can-reference-python-function-inside-itself)).

Comment: I just need to add this section to many tasks and want to reduce possible errors in future.If I can call a retry without specifing the function/task name it simplify it.