# Is it possible to check if a function is decorated inside another function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is there any way to check inside function `f1` in my example if calling a function (here `decorated` or `not_decorated`) has a specific decorator (in code `@out`)? Is such information passed to a function?

```
def out(fun):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@out
def decorated():
    f1()

def not_decorated():
    f1()

def f1():
    if is_decorated_by_out: # here I want to check it
        print('I am')
    else:
        print('I am not')

decorated()
not_decorated()
```

Expected output:

```
I am
I am not
```

Comment: You could add an attribute to the function `out()` returns whose existence could be checked in `f1()`.

Comment: Having a function try to inspect anything at all about the code calling it is generally a last resort - you should try to find other ways to get the necessary information into your function, or reconsider whether you really need it.

Comment: I changed `in` to `inner`. `in` is a reserved word so calling or returning `in` is not going to work

Comment: Your decorator could, in theory, set an attribute on the function that it is decorating. The main problem is that a function can't reference itself (so you can't check if `f1` has that attribute inside of `f1`), you will need another decorator just for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063607/is-there-a-generic-way-for-a-function-to-reference-itself

Comment: "Decorating" a function does not in and of itself leave any trace. `@out def decoratd()...` is just syntactic sugar for `def decorated(): ...; decorated = out(decorated)`.

Comment: In this specific case, however, note that `decorated.__name__ == "inner"`, while `not_decorated.__name__ == "not_decorated"`. (Not that `f1` knows, absent the kind of introspection mentioned by user2357112, who its caller is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, this is egregious hackery, so I don't recommend it, but since you've ruled out additional parameters, and `f1` will be the same whether wrapped or not, you've left hacks as your only option. The solution is to add a local variable to the wrapper function for the sole purpose of being found by means of stack inspection:

```
import inspect

def out(fun):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        __wrapped_by__ = out
        fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

def is_wrapped_by(func):
    try:
        return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_back.f_locals.get('__wrapped_by__') is func
    except AttributeError:
        return False

@out
def decorated():
    f1()

def not_decorated():
    f1()

def f1():
    if is_wrapped_by(out):
        print('I am')
    else:
        print('I am not')

decorated()
not_decorated()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBisMgEIbvPoW3mLAElr0tFHrdpxBrxq40URknlD591okhdNvSuTjMr///OelGvzF8LYufUkSSPuQEloQYwMk4k3JzaL@FLMUTHwKg6gye84fsusuVu03n0vqKJiUY9OmmtTywxS4Wq6enq4hAM4ZqXpN9vjNiBruF7FdXzN7OiBDIoZlAtb3TJ2MvT8cYrRlzfwZSzX/Cpi1RDGaFODIrhw9gIxqCQW2h7lO1lStE0m9k7urMP/6hmN/tKaEPBeZHmqmpO4Axw0udM5vVf48VDxjL8gc)

This assumes a specific degree of nesting (the manual back-tracking via `f_back` to account for `is_wrapped_by` itself, `f1`, `decorated` and finally to `inner` (from `out`). If you want to determine if `out` was involved *anywhere* in the call stack, make `is_wrapped_by` loop until the stack is exhausted:

```
def is_wrapped_by(func):
    frame = None
    try:
        # Skip is_wrapped_by and caller 
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
        while True:
            if frame.f_locals.get('__wrapped_by__') is func:
                return True
            frame = frame.f_back
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    finally:
        # Leaving frame on the call stack can cause cycle involving locals
        # which delays cleanup until cycle collector runs;
        # explicitly break cycle to save yourself the headache
        del frame
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to creating an additional parameter in `f1` (you could also use a default parameter), you can use `functools.wraps` and check for the existence of the `__wrapped__` attribute. To do so, pass the wrapper function to `f`:

```
import functools

def out(fun):
  @functools.wraps(fun)
  def inner(*args, **kwargs):
     fun(*args, **kwargs)
  return inner

@out
def decorated():
  f1(decorated)

def not_decorated():
  f1(not_decorated)

def f1(_func):
  if getattr(_func, '__wrapped__', False):
    print('I am')
  else:
    print('I am not')

decorated()
not_decorated()
```

Output:

```
I am 
I am not
```

Comment: Good solution, but I can't create a new parameter in `f()`. This is a big obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function decoration like this one

```
def double_arg(fun):
    def inner(x):
        return fun(x*2)
    return inner
```

however you can't access it (it's inside a 3rd party lib or something). In this case you can wrap it into another function that adds the name of the decoration to the resulting function

```
def keep_decoration(decoration):
    def f(g):
        h = decoration(g)
        h.decorated_by = decoration.__name__
        return h
    return f
```

and replace the old decoration by the wrapper.

```
double_arg = keep_decoration(double_arg)
```

You can even write a helper function that checks whether a function is decorated or not.

```
def is_decorated_by(f, decoration_name):
    try:
        return f.decorated_by == decoration_name
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Example of use...

```
@double_arg
def inc_v1(x):
    return x + 1

def inc_v2(x):
    return x + 1

print(inc_v1(5))
print(inc_v2(5))

print(is_decorated_by(inc_v1, 'double_arg'))
print(is_decorated_by(inc_v2, 'double_arg'))
```

Output

```
11
6
True
False
```